# Terminology/resources for descriptions like "...the other one..."

Tags: terminology, semantics, reference-request, anaphora

Suppose, e.g., that there are two brothers, Bob and Bill, that must do two things but it doesn't much matter which brother does which task. I am interested in constructions like the following:

> One brother should do TASK 1 and *the other one* should complete TASK 2.

"One brother" is indifferent between Bob and Bill, but once one of the brothers is selected "...the other one..." must refer to the other brother.

Is there a special term for descriptions like this? It seems like maybe it is a case of [complement anaphora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics)#Complement_anaphora)? What is a good place to read more about phenomena like this?

Comment: _One_ and _the/an other_ are sometimes called "reciprocals", and can get fused into the construction _one another_ or used separately as in the example. In terms of POS, they're quantifiers, a species of determiner.